# При margin-top опускается родительский div

Tags: html, css

Смотрите какой простой код

```css
.wrap {
    max-width: 1885px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.slider {
    background-image: url("../img/slide1.png");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.logo {
    background-image: url("../img/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 414px;
    height: 81px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="mainNav">
          <li>О нас</li>
          <li>Юридическим лицам</li>
          <li>Физическим лицам</li>
          <li>Карта сайта</li>
          <li>Интернет</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

И вот собственно вопрос, почему когда я ставлю у `.logo` `margin: 20px 0 0 0;` за лого опускается и `.slider`, а не остается прижатым к экрану?

PS - и если у `.logo` заменить `margin` на `padding` то отступ исчезает совсем- почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у родительского эл-та нет ограничивающих факторов, то `margin` переходит от внутреннего элемента к внешнему. Потом `margin` выбирается по схеме: если они одноименные, то выбирается больший, если разноименные, то происходит сложение.

Можно отменить это действие по отношению к родителю, есть несколько способов:

1. задать `padding` родительскому блоку;
2. задать `border` родительскому блоку;
3. задать `overflow` родительскому блоку, любое значение кроме
   `visible`( работает везде, кроме старых ИЕ );

Соответственно решить можно так:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="logo">1</div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="mainNav">
                    <li>О нас</li>
                    <li>Юридическим лицам</li>
                    <li>Физическим лицам</li>
                    <li>Карта сайта</li>
                    <li>Интернет</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>  
    </div>
</header> 
</body>
</html>

body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap{
    max-width: 1885px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.slider{
    background-image: url("../img/slide1.png");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top:20px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.logo{
    background-image: url("../img/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 414px;
    height: 81px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

PS. `margin` это внешний отступ, `padding` - внутренний.